# How to make "auto" type deduction compatible with range-based "for"?

Tags: c++, type-deduction, range-based-loop

I am learning to make the self-defined class compatible with the range-based 'for' loop.

Given the range class:

```
class range
{
private:

    range_iterator m_begin;
    range_iterator m_end;

public:

    range()
    :
        m_begin(0),
        m_end(9)
    {}

    range_iterator begin()
    {
        return m_begin;
    }

    range_iterator end()
    {
        return m_end;
    }

};
```

And the iterator:

```
class range_iterator
{
public:

    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = int;
    using pointer           = int*;
    using reference         = int&;


    range_iterator(int val)
    :
        m_int(val)
    {}

    int value() const
    {
        return m_int;
    }

    range_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++m_int;
        return *(this);
    }

    int operator*()
    {
        return m_int;
    }

    bool operator!=(const range_iterator &rhs)
    {
        return ( m_int != rhs.value() );
    }

private:

    int m_int;

};
```

And the main function:

```
int main()
{
    range r0;

    for (auto r : r0)
    {}

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that r is 'auto' deduced as 'int' type.

How to make the 'auto' type deduction of r to be 'range_iterator' ?

I am confused why the type of r is not the same as returned by range::begin()/end()

Comment: you misunderstood ranged based loops. In  `for (auto r : r0)` the `r` is a copy of the elements in `r0`, it is not an iterator.

Comment: if you want iterators do not use a range based loop

Comment: I think you misunderstand what [range `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) really does and how it works. It iterates over the *values* in the container, using the iterators internally.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. But how to make it right? Could you please give an example?

Comment: what is wrong? What you call "problem" is none.

Comment: code seems to be fine https://godbolt.org/z/3va3zvdPq. You should write more tests to see if it does what you want it to do

Comment: for (range_iterator r : r0) {}. This is fine.

Comment: `for (range_iterator r : r0)` range based loops do not work like that. Please read the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). You can iterate over iterators when you have a range of iterators. When you have a range of `int`s then the range based loop iterates `int`s

Comment: Then how to define such a range of iterators that (auto r) will be an iterator?

Comment: That's just not how range for works, you can't do what you want. Please tell us the problem with looping over the values instead of over the iterators? What is the reason you need to use iterators? What is the original and underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Your question in its current for is unfortunately an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: As for using iterators, you need a non-range `for` loop: `for (auto iterator = r0.begin(); iterator != r0.end(); ++iterator) { ... /* Use the iterator */ ... }`

Comment: The orignial problem is that for a container ```class c```, ```c``` has its own iterater. But I want to implement a function ```c::items()``` so that ```for (auto it : c0.items())``` will work. And ```it``` will be an iterator

Comment: It seems that I get it why ```auto r``` is of type int.  The type should be the same as that of ```( *  r0.begin())```

Comment: But ***why*** does it need to be an iterator? Why can't you loop over the *values* in the nested container? What are you doing inside your actual loop, in your actual code?

Comment: And to nitpick, the type of `*r0.begin()` *is* an `int`. Because when you dereference the iterator you get an `int` value.